# Sort list by "order" column like how view columns can be rearranged?

Tags: list, custom-list

I've got a SP2010 custom list, where the customer wants to be able to set an order for items in the list. I created an "order" column, it's a numeric column, where you type in a number, and we can sort on it.

But what is *really* desired is for that "order" column to work the way it does when creating a list view and setting column display ordering; you change a column's ordering, and wah-lah, the entire list re-orders itself accordingly.

Anybody aware of a means of achieving a similar functionality for a list?

**Update to clarify:** I am *not* talking about simply sorting the list on the "Order" column. Already got that. What I'm talking about is some means to automatically reorder all the related rows in the list. If I had 5 items in the list, and one item is "3" for the "Order", and I change it to a "2"; the other list entries would update on the fly. If you use Netflix and reorder something in your queue, that's what I'm thinking of. Or if you edit the column ordering in a view, you see similar behavior. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this. Change the 'Order' column settings to "Ensure Unique values" .

Then go to List settings -> Sort ->  Select "First sort by the column:" Order. Select either ascending or descending order.

Hope this is what you are looking for to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can **modify** the view of the specific list and under the sort option choose "order".

List settings -> view (eg. All Items)

There is also a "Modify View" shortcut in the List Tools -> List tab of the Ribbon in the "Manage Views" box.

From here you can choose which columns to display, the grouping of the columns, specify the sorting or a filter and more.